# how to open dynamic URL scheme in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme

I want to make an app that opens URL schemes that entered by user.  
I found it is necessary to add the URL scheme in `info.plist` and `info.plist` isn't changed dynamically. 
But I saw some app that have this function. 

I need to open URL schemes that managed by users(add/update/delete), what should I do? 
Please help me T.T

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible, and even if you can hack it, it's a security risk, so I'm sure Apple would reject such app.

Answer (score 0):

The domain itself should be in `info.plist`, but what you can handle inside the code is after the domain. For example: `yourdomain.com/add` or `yourdomain.com/update`.
Then inside your code when you handle the URL scheme you can check for the string after your domain.